# Jenkins Patterns: View jobs with Pattern in name

Tags: jenkins

I am looking for a pattern to allow users to view every job with "DB_" in the name.

The following allows only the view of jobs that start with "DB_"

```
^DB_.*$
```

I need to be able to view these "DB_" jobs no matter where it is in the name:

```
DB_canview_yay
this_DB_jobisviewable
this_oneto0_DB_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^.*DB_.*$` should do it.

The `^` character anchors to the beginning, the `$` character anchors to the end, and `.*` matches 0 or more other characters.

Comment: Works! Thanks Dave!